# Добавление новой записи в структуру - массив

Tags: c

//Добавление новых записей
template <typename newType> newType  *set_New_Records(newType* ptrArr,int Size)
{
    newType *mov_Buffer=new newType[Size];

```
char *Array=new char[20];

for(int i=0;i<Size-1;i++)
{
    mov_Buffer[i]=ptrArr[i];        
}

delete[]ptrArr;
ptrArr=mov_Buffer;

cout<<"Введите название фильма "<<endl;
gets(Array);
strncpy(mov_Buffer[Size-1].Name_Film, Array, Size_Text);
cout<<"Введите фамилию режиссера "<<endl;
gets(Array);
strncpy(mov_Buffer[Size-1].Directed_By, Array, Size_Text);
cout<<"Введите жанр фильма "<<endl;
gets(Array);
strncpy(mov_Buffer[Size-1].Genre, Array, Size_Text);
cout<<"Введите рейтинг фильма "<<endl;
cin>>mov_Buffer[Size-1].Rating;
cout<<"Введите стоимость диска "<<endl;
cin>>mov_Buffer[Size-1].Price;

for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
{
    strncpy(ptrArr[i].Name_Film, mov_Buffer[i].Name_Film, Size_Text);
    strncpy(ptrArr[i].Directed_By, mov_Buffer[i].Directed_By, Size_Text);
    strncpy(ptrArr[i].Genre, mov_Buffer[i].Genre, Size_Text);
    ptrArr[i].Rating=mov_Buffer[i].Rating;
    ptrArr[i].Price=mov_Buffer[i].Price;
}

delete[]Array;
return ptrArr;  
Вопрос решен так
```

Comment: @Freerider, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете в c++. [Так используйте c++!](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C++))

Answer (score 0):

Для *nix см. `man memcpy`.

Если же немного отойти от канонов C++, то для распределения памяти можно использовать функции `malloc/realloc` (впрочем, достаточно одной realloc() (см. соответствующий man)).

Answer (score 0):

В с++ для строк (массив типа char) используют тип [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) или [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), как советует [[@Zelta](/users/11139/zelta)](/users/11139/zelta).